# what is the meaning of the "tip into"?

Tags: word-meaning

For now, though, the reality is that we live in a society of, intense complexity, one more factor that contributes to the growing squeeze on energy and other natural resources. In calculating how close we are to Peaks and Absolute Peaks, it's important understand how complexities burden the search for solutions. In fact, complexity could well be **the straw that tips into** Game Over.

I can't clearly understand the last sentence. Could you please explain me the idea?

Comment: it's important *to* understand...

Comment: It's rather like saying *The elephant in the room is the straw that broke the camel's back.*

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear, because the writer is using a couple of images or metaphors without spelling them out.

The meaning is comparing it to a see-saw: the "Game Over" suggests a video game, and specifically one where there are gadgets that tilt and send you into a pit or other hazard when something lands on them.

But it is also references the idiom *the last straw*, which goes back to the proverb *It's the last straw that breaks the camel's back*.

So altogether the sentence means that complexity is the small thing (*the straw*) which, when added to whatever is there already  *tips*, or tilts, the see-saw, sending the "game" into failure- "Game Over".

Comment: +1 "the straw that broke the camel's back" is commonly used.